# Azure: I am unable to select VM size through portal (all browsers) - Powershell seems to work OK

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal, azure-resource-group

It seems that for my new Azure account I get the "crying cloud" every time I attempt to create a new resource through the web portal. I tried all browsers {including Edge! ;)} even in private mode. 
All failed in "Select a VM size" - I am unable to create a new resource through portal!
The MS chat suggested I wait for a few hours after the creation of my new account for the size picker to work... It has been a day :/

I have tried Azure PowerShell, both times successfully at creating a new VM!-

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, TY!

Added screenshots of the affected laptop for clarity..

[the selection screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08r9p.png)

[the error in the size selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9pGl.png)

Comment: Could you show some screenshots? any error or just hanging for a long time.

Comment: No errors at all I am afraid, just the crying cloud in the middle and every refresh gives same...

Comment: try another pc, preferably with a different internet connection. turn off firewalls etc

Comment: Is this happening for particular region, Can you kindly share the screenshot of the portal "issue"

Comment: I tried 4c74356b41's suggestion (a different laptop was used - same ISP connection, no particular firewalls setup, same firefox ver, etc) and it worked like a charm!! Thank you so much! (the original PC used for opening the account still can't access the size setting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another pc, preferably with a different internet connection. turn off firewalls etc – kudos to contributor 4c74356b41 my attempt with a different pc was successful.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a browser issue, more a subscription issue.

You should contact Microsoft with a billing ticket, its free.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to be related to the specific laptop that was used to open the account - it works perfectly with another (same os, browser, isp, etc)